# Logo and Header text not aligned and overlapped

Tags: html, css

I'm new at web-based programming and I've been having trouble on the header, the logo and the text always seems to overlap, I've been trying some floats and adjusting the size of the header but doesn't seem to budge. This is my code:

CSS:

```css
#container{
    width: 1040px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    border: 10px solid white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

#header{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    margin:15x auto;
    padding: 4px;
    overflow:hidden;    
}

.headpart{
    width:60%;
    height:auto;
    vertical-align:top;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    font-size:28px;
}

img{
    position:absolute;
    vertical-align:top;
    float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tampilan.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>home</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<div class="headpart">
<img src="image/logo.jpg" width=135px height=120px>
<p id="pheader"> Lembaga Pengkajian Pangan Obat obatan dan Kosmetika Majelis Ulama Indonesia</p>
</div>
</div>

    <div id="isi">
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div id="side"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove `position:absolute;` under `img` in the CSS.  This'll make everything inline (assuming that's what you want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can use this code.
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kalusingh/u8AKw/)

```
        <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
        <div class="headpart">
        <img src="image/logo.jpg" width=135px height=120px>
            <p id="pheader"> Lembaga Pengkajian Pangan Obat obatan dan Kosmetika Majelis Ulama Indonesia</p>

    </div>
    </div>

        <div id="isi">
            <div id="content"></div>
            <div id="side"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>


    #container
{
width:1040px;
margin:30px auto;
border: 10px solid black;
border-radius: 20px;
background-color:red;
}

#header
{
width:100%;
height:200px;
margin:15px auto;
padding: 4px;
overflow:hidden;
}

.headpart
{
width:60%;
height:auto;
vertical-align:top;
position:relative;
float:left;
font-size:20px;
}

img
{
position:absolute;
vertical-align:top;
float:left;
}
p
{
    margin-left:150px;
}
```

Comment: It did help, although I already found a matching code like yours, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/USf36/)

```
#container{
  width: 1040px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border: 10px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
}

#header{
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  margin:15x auto;
  padding: 4px;
  overflow:hidden;    
}

.headpart{
  width:60%;
  height:auto;
  vertical-align:top;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  font-size:28px;
  }

 img{
   vertical-align:top;
   float: left;
 }
```